# The preferred replica is unavailable - Microsoft Graph

Tags: entra-id, microsoft, azureadconnect, microsoft-graph

While creating user using `microsoft graph`,it was working fine yesterday but now I am getting the error below. I re-activated the subscription.

```
   "error": {
        "code": "Directory_ReplicaUnavailable",
        "message": "The preferred replica is unavailable. Please retry your request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "19030bd0-0aad-49cf-9d40-6fcb7fb4360e",
            "date": "2020-05-08T14:35:45"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, don't think anyone would be able to solve this, you'll have to contact Microsoft support for more details.

Comment: @NoorKhaldi thanks. It was solved by Microsoft